# CsvHelper cannot read double values

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

I have this code to read a simple CSV file with the CsvHelper library

```
public class CSVData
    {
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public double Value1 { get; set; }
        public double Value2 { get; set; }
        public double Value3 { get; set; }
    }

using (var reader = new StreamReader("c:\\temp\\test.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
{
   var records = csv.GetRecords<CSVData>();
}
```

and this is how th CSV data looks

```
"Time","Value1","Value2","Value3"
 8/28/2019 4:32:09 PM,2.03,10229.73,10437.51821998
```

and I get this error when I try to read the records with

```
 foreach (CSVData item in records)

CsvHelper.BadDataException: 'You can ignore bad data by setting BadDataFound to null.'
```

Comment: I have added "Value3",  with comma after but I get the same error

Comment: What other values have you tested? Are you sure it is the first value and not one of the doubles? What if you remove the double values? Did you try quote enclosing the values? You need to do a little more troubleshooting yourself to figure out exactly what value or combination of values or formatting is causing your problem.

Comment: You got that error when you tried to read, _which record?_  If you put a breakpoint at the area where it failed, what was the specific CSVData record you were attempting to parse?

Comment: I have removed the first column and I get the same error

Comment: @gravity the error comes at all the records, I cannot read anything

Comment: @gravity I get the error in this line foreach (CSVData item in records)

Comment: Your original post said the error was on `csv.GetRecords<CSVData>();` now, it appears you're trying to enumerate through the data.  What are you doing in the foreach?  Please post a *complete* [mcve], as your code works perfectly fine as shown.

Comment: @gravity it fails exactly in the foreach, and I don't have any other code in the foreach yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code actually worked fine for me as long as you use the US culture setting for double (using a . decimal point).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);

        List<CSVData> records;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader("test.csv"))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
        {
            records = csv.GetRecords<CSVData>().ToList();
        }

        foreach (var r in records)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Time:{r.Time} Value1:{r.Value1} Value2:{r.Value2} Value3:{r.Value3}");
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
Time: 8/28/2019 4:32:09 PM Value1:2.03 Value2:10229.73 Value3:10437.51821998
```

Comment: it is possible that we have different locale? for double format?

Comment: What does a double look like if you print one from your code using double.ToString()? Are you using , for the decimal point?

Comment: how can I specify the locale for CsvHelper?

Comment: my locale is with comma separator, not dot

Comment: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);

Comment: Yes, now it works. please add this to your answer so I can choose your answer. Thanks!

Comment: This is one thing I personally think should have been done differently. CsvHelper's delimiter defaults to the current culture's delimiter rather than a comma. Explicitly setting the delimiter in the configuration is usually the recommended solution.

Comment: It's not the delimiter, it's the way the numbers are represented (we expect a dot but some cultures use the comma for the decimal point). The problem is on his PC, CSVHelper would not work for example 10229.73 there would be a ParseException on double.Parse()

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I would still probably set it in the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the culture info in the configuration. You may also need to set the delimiter.

```cs
using (var reader = new StreamReader("c:\\temp\\test.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
{
    csv.Configuration.CultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);

    csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";

    var records = csv.GetRecords<CSVData>();
}
```

Comment: thanks!, but looks like the locale format of double numbers was the problem

Comment: Gotcha.  You can also set the `CultureInfo` in the configuration.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know how, I am new to CsvHelper

Comment: After playing around with other CultureInfo's.  It looks like you may need to also set the delimiter if your CurrentCulture uses something different than a comma.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set CultureInfo to CurrentCulture.

> csv.Configuration.CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;